# How to use autoprefixer with svelte?

Tags: css, npm, svelte, postcss, autoprefixer

I've tried to piece together how to get autoprefixer to work in svelte from the few posts hanging about but have been unsuccessful.

I ran `npm install postcss postcss-cli autoprefixer` in my root directory and my package.json now has

```
"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.25",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
    // some other stuff
}
```

Then i modified my `svelte.config.js` to

```
import sveltePreprocess from "svelte-preprocess";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";

export default {
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ postcss: { plugins: [autoprefixer()] } }),
};
```

I created a `postcss.config.js` file in the root folder and put inside

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
};
```

I also created a `.browserslistrc` file in root folder and put in it

```
> 1%
```

Then i ran `npm run dev`. However, when i look at bundle.css, there are no vendor prefix css properties. How can i get this to work?

Comment: But what does `npm run dev`? What's your bundler? Can you share your setup in an example repo so ppl can reproduce it?

Comment: @hackape I'm not sure, i initialised my project by cloning from https://github.com/sveltejs/template, is rollup the bundler?

Comment: Yeah Rollup is the bundler. I'm not entirely sure what's wrong but this template is pretty old. It could be that earlier version of `sveltePreprocess` does not support PostCSS.

Comment: It looks like you're using newer versions of the package for a really old and deprecated svelte template. If you are still trying to use the older version, then you should go to the archive and find out what version of these packages were being used, otherwise I suggest to use `npm init vite` and choose the `svelte` option for a newer svelte template

Comment: @JoshuaQ can i do that in my existing project without breaking things?

Comment: @LolLol, you can try using the [svelte-migrate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-migrate) command and see if it can do most of the work. There would definitely some changes you have to manually do, since it's such a huge jump.

Comment: would it be easier to just copy out my src and public folders, wipe the entire thing, start a new project and copy the files back in?

Comment: That is definitely a way to do it. But be aware of the different changes that you have to make, like filenames and folder structures and some configurations. From the examples you gave me, it looks like you don't have to change much and this would be the easiest way to updgrade *as long as it's not a massive project*

Comment: You also would want to put the autoprefixer inside of the postcss.config.js